# Calculating 2D beacons position based on accuracy

Tags: ios, ibeacon, beacon

I have two beacons at known positions.
How to calculate the exact 2d position of iPhone between two beacons based on accuracy.

Comment: You should need 3 beacons (at least) to do that.

Comment: I don't need triangulation, all beacons have same y coordinate.

Comment: Do you assume that you have the same y coordinate too?

Comment: Yes, all beacons with same y coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a good result finally, in order if some one needs the solution:

I have considered the p1 and p2 as center of two circles.

Then I have calculated the distance between two centers (two points distance formula) like this: `double dx = (b.x-a.x);
    double dy = (b.y-a.y);
    double dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);`
Then I have found a base formula to limit the approximate accuracy to the distance between two points (p1, p2)

```
double l = dist / (dA + dB);
```

Now I got two circles with known centers and calculate the radius based on accuracy and limit

```
float r1 = l * dA;
float r2 = l * dB;
```

Now there are two circles with known centers and radius intersecting in single point which is the position of mobile.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with jrturton. It'll only work in highly controlled conditions **and with three beacons** and the result will be far from perfect. Here's what happens when you calculate with two beacons:

Just look at it as a triangle.

[image]

By using the [distance formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html) you have two equations:

*20m = sqrt( ( 1 - iPhone.x )^2 + ( 2 - iPhone.y )^2)

40m = sqrt( ( 10 - iPhone.x)^2 + ( 2 - iPhone.y )^2)*

Now you need to solve for `iPhone.x` and `iPhone.y`

20 ^ 2 = ( 1 - iPhone.x )^2 + ( 2 - iPhone.y )^2
40 ^ 2 = ( 10 - iPhone.x)^2 + ( 2 - iPhone.y )^2

So these are equations for circles and you have to calculate the point at [which they're touching](http://www.mathsmutt.co.uk/files/tcirc.htm).

You'll receive two points, not one.

[image]

**You can't know the exact position from just two beacons.**

**As somebody mentioned in the comments, you need three beacons to do that.**

Answer (score 4):

You can't. All the maths in the world won't change the fact that the RSSI reading you get from beacons fluctuates wildly and in response to dozens of factors outside of your control.

The best you can do is to roughly say which beacons you are near, and very roughly how near they are. Any attempt to be more precise than that *will* fail as soon as you test in a real world environment.

Comment: Yep, it'll only work in perfectly controlled conditions. And the accuracy will be far from perfect.